# Session variable being lost in different browsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies

I'm using a session variable to store an id, which I'm in turn using to represent a shopping basket. I'm setting the value using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Session["MyId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

This is set at the end of an Action method and then I redirect to another Action, where I then read the value using:

```
HttpContext.Session["MyId"].ToString();
```

The last line works all the time in Chrome and sometimes in IE, but rarely in Mozilla. Any idea why that could be? These page clicks (RedirectToAction() statements) are happening instantly and not at a later time when you might expect the session to have expired.